# MPV is not printing its console text on the CMD window it was launched from

Tags: windows, command-line, mpv

This used to work before but now for some reason it does not. I tried deleting all my config files to see if some preference was turning of console output, I also copied just the `mpv.exe` to another folder and tried running it. It did not work.

In all cases, when I open a file with mpv `mpv.exe vid.mp4` no console output is shown at all:
This reddit user, [How to actually show the terminal/console?](https://old.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/e760qs/how_to_actually_show_the_terminalconsole/) was dealing with a similar issue, they did not seem to solve it though.
Here is a screenshot of my screen:
[image: |500]

What could be causing this?